# Проблемы с изображениями при работе с hugo

Tags: изображения, static

В общем столкнулся с проблемой, как включить изображения в документацию, перепробовал способы популярные в интернете, без результата. Hugo не видит каталоги и сами картинки. Плюс сама выбранная тема так и осталась не кастомизированной. При использовании pandoc ссылки на изображения 75% перестают работать, есть подозрение, что на hugo просто не прописаны настройки для обработки изображений. Если в дальнейшем не получиться в большем проценте "подтягивать" картинки в документацию, останется только ручной режим вставки изображений непосредственно в разметку. Что довольно таки трудоемко, и не знаю на сколько рационально по сравнению с нынешней ситуацией или другим инструментом. Прошу в данный момент в первую очередь помощи с разъяснением ситуации с подтягиванием картинок в доку, и во вторую очередь помощи с кастомизацией и допиливанием темы для сайта.

Comment: Уточните какая область интересует (разработка или администрирование) и используемые технологии а также укажите подходящие теги. Под "hugo" - Вы имеете ввиду это [hugo](https://gohugo.io/)?

Comment: скорее администрирование, да имеется в виду hugo для генерации статичных сайтов.